Cloth Simulation For A-Pose Creates Too Many Wrinkles/Wet T-Shirt Look
I am new to cloth simulation so I'm hoping that this is a simple fix.
I have modeled a shirt on a metahuman character which I will be using in Unreal Engine. To create the shirt, I positioned the character in a standard T Pose. I am pleased with the results considering I'm new to this.
The next step is to put the shirt into the standard "A" pose which metahumans use for the rest position so I can transfer the weights from the base mesh. I found a tutorial that suggested taking your shirt mesh, applying a second cloth simulation, and then animating the base pose to go from the T-pose into the A-pose rest position.
I implemented this and technically it does work, however, it produces some strange results on the shirt itself, essentially making it look like it shrunk and became a wet T-shirt...lol  See images below.
Any suggestions on settings or fixes to prevent the shirt from changing shape like this during this second cloth sim?  Or maybe there's a better way to accomplish this?
Original Shirt:

The result after the second cloth sim to put it into the A pose:

Here are screen shots of my cloth sim settings.  Note, anything which is collapsed remains at the default settings:



Hello could you please share your file?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Have you applied a Subdivision Surface modifier in screenshot 2? It seems to have way more vertices than in screenshot 1 hence the wet appearance.

No subdivision surface modifier in the second screenshot.  I have the modifier tab open in the image, and the only modifier is the cloth simulation.

Duarte, quite honestly, I couldn't figure out how to describe this question in a way that would make a better title since I don't know what exactly is happening...lol

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?
